# USFM: This file was explicity re-assigned to plain text

Tags: intellij-idea, text

I have a IntelliJ project with a number of USFM files. These files have the extension usfm. When I open one of these files, there's a warning at the top that says `This file was explicitly re-assigned to plain text` with the options `Remove association` and `Edit File Types`.

It's not really a problem, but it is annoying. It is also the single warning when I commit that makes me press commit anyway.

When I check the file types, I have USFM listed as a text file. I'm guessing this is the explicit part. I'm not sure how to stop this warning from coming up.

This is only irritating, but it's a big project and it's getting on my nerves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the inspection or remove the file type, see the inspection description:

> Reports files that were explicitly re-assigned to Plain Text File
> Type. This association is unnecessary because the platform
> auto-detects text files by content automatically. You can dismiss this
> warning by removing the file type association in Settings | Editor |
> File Types | Text.

[image: inspection]

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me at all, but it worked. Thanks for the help!